# Implement facebook connect in Pyrocms

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, pyrocms

I need to implement facebook connect in Pyrocms based site.The user module is working fine but now I want to allow the user to be able to login into the site using facebook account.So please let me know is there any add ons which is fulfilling my requirement or I have to write the code own.I case i have to write the code what algorith i have to follow...
Please help.

Comment: have you tried the topic in my answer?

Comment: ya i have gone through that but i dont want to use Social Integration Addon..I have to code it myself....:( Please share your thoughts on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this at http://dev.mypartyaid.com/users/login here ....

Answer (score 3):

With [Social Integration](http://www.pyrocms.com/store/details/social_integration) you can allow user to login with their facebook acocunt, you only need to modify the controller as they said in this [topic](http://www.pyrocms.com/forums/topics/view/12505/10). 
It worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Social Integration](http://www.pyrocms.com/store/details/social_integration) addon.

Comment: have you used this addon, basically i only need the functionality of facebook login. It should allow user to access all the functionalty which a registered user can access.....!!!